# construct json object in Angular with dynamic field names

Tags: json, angular

newbie question: is there a better way to construct json object in Angular? Currently I can only do the following:

```
var fieldName1 = 'name1';
var fieldValue1 = 'value1';
var fieldName2 = 'name2';
var fieldValue2 = 'value2';

//**failed to compile**
// var result = {{fieldName1:fieldValue1},{fieldName2,fieldValue2}};

var object1 = {};
object1[`${fieldName1}`] = fieldValue1;
var object2 = {};
object2[`${fieldName2}`] = fieldValue2;

var result = {object1, object2};
```

The field names "name1", "name2" are not static values.
The expected result is:

```
{
  { name1 : "value1" },
  { name2 : "value2" }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Run The Snippet  , you will get the idea :

```js
var fieldName1 = 'name1';
var fieldValue1 = 'value1';
var fieldName2 = 'name2';
var fieldValue2 = 'value2';

var object = {};
object[fieldName1] = fieldValue1;
object[fieldName2] = fieldValue2;

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
let object = {}
for(let field of allFields){
    object[field] = value
}
```

Here `allFields` is an array with all fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to make the array of value into JSON Object.

```
var fieldName = ['name1','name2'];
var fieldValue =['value1','value2'];
var object = {};
  for(i=0;i<fieldName.length;i++){
    object[fieldName[i]]=fieldValue[i];
   }
  console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var fieldName1 = 'name1';
var fieldValue1 = 'value1';
var fieldName2 = 'name2';
var fieldValue2 = 'value2';
var object = {};
object[fieldName1] = fieldValue1;
object[fieldName2] = fieldValue2;
object = JSON.stringify(object);
object=object.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :**

- `expected result` in OP is not having a valid JSON.

  [image]

**Solutions :**

- **Array of objects :**

```js
var fieldName1 = 'name1';
var fieldValue1 = 'value1';
var fieldName2 = 'name2';
var fieldValue2 = 'value2';

var object1 = {};
var object2 = {};

object1[fieldName1] = fieldValue1;
object2[fieldName2] = fieldValue2;

console.log(new Array(object1, object2));
```

- **single object with multiple properties :**

```js
var fieldName1 = 'name1';
var fieldValue1 = 'value1';
var fieldName2 = 'name2';
var fieldValue2 = 'value2';

var jsonObject = {};

jsonObject[fieldName1] = fieldValue1;
jsonObject[fieldName2] = fieldValue2;

console.log(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let object = {};
someRequest.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
    object[key]=value;
})
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24053291).

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 11 or greater, you need declare the type, example:

```
type tplotOptions = {
    [key: string]: boolean
}
const plotOptions: tplotOptions = {
    train_1: true,
    train_2: true
}
```

or

```
type tplotOptions = {
    [key: string]: string
}
const plotOptions: tplotOptions = {
    train_1: 'data1',
    train_2: 'data2'
}
```